# vimscript: add functionality to mouse click with key mapping

Tags: vim

I use vim in xterms on Arch linux. Wanting to automatically set marks for subsequent command ranges I wrote this mapping

```
map <LeftMouse> mp:let g:oc=g:nc<cr>:let g:nc=getpos('.')<cr>:call setpos("'o", g:oc)<cr>:call cursor(g:nc[1], g:nc[2])<cr>
```

but now the mouse no longer places the cursor at the clicked location.  How can I keep standard mouse function, and add to it rather than replacing it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems its not possible to modify LeftMouse, but you can achieve the effect of it using LeftRelease.  So my mapping does what I want as

```
nmap <LeftRelease> mp:let g:oc=g:nc<cr>:let g:nc=getpos('.')<cr>:call setpos("'o", g:oc)<cr>
```

and the standard function of  is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can `:set mouse=a` for using visual select mode. (This is not what you wanted but it is a trick).
Then, click on text, you will see that it is getting selected. Then, you can release it.

A mapping like

```
 :map gv ma
```

will set the last recently selected text as mark a.

**Other way:**

Instead of `:set mouse=a`, you can press `v` and then select a letter or a word, depending upon your convenience and then `ma` for marking it as mark `a`.
A short mapping for it will be

```
:map vly ma
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to achieve the result, marking ranges for commands/functions, by using something i already was doing - clicking the mouse to relocate the cursor.  I finally settled on this mapping: 'nnoremap <silent> <LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>:call setpos("'o", getpos("'p"))<cr>mp'.  I hadn't understood the use of nnoremap, without it the mapping would just produce an endlessly repeated click.

Comment: Now, you have found a solution, isn't?